# size of two dimension array

Tags: arrays, c, size

```
int main()
{
    int a[3][4] = {
        
        {0, 1, 2, 3} ,   //  initializers for 0 row
        {4, 5, 6, 7} ,   //  initializers for 1 row
        {8, 9, 10, 11}   //  initializers for 2 row
    };

    int b[3][4] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
    
    

    printf("size of *a = %ld\n", sizeof(*a));
    printf("size of *b = %ld\n", sizeof(*b));
//these prints out 16.
//why is this 16?
```

Hello, I am learning c in school and I have a question.
why is the size of a(and b) 16?? How does it work?

Comment: `sizeof a` is 48. `sizeof *a` is 16

Comment: You code is printing the sizes of `*a` and `*b`, i.e. `a[0]` and `b[0]`.  These have type `int [4]`.  Their sizes are therefore `4 * sizeof(int)`.  If you want the size of `a`, use `sizeof(a)`, not `sizeof(*a)`.  Then you'll get `3*4*sizeof(int)`, which is presumably what you're looking for.

Comment: @stark thank you for your comment. size of a is 12 integer * 4bytes, is it correct?

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you !! *a is a pointer(first array), and that contains 4 integer, then which is size 16. Is it correct?

Comment: `*a` does not have a pointer type.  It has an array type.  It will be *converted* to a pointer in certain contexts, but being an argument to `sizeof` is not one of them.  Try printing `sizeof(int [4])`.  It will be the same as `sizeof(*a)`.  Both have array types.

Comment: a is 12 integers, *a is 4 integers, **a is 1 integer.